# I want to use an argument on a function which has an user-defined datatype, and call the function in a trigger

Tags: function, plsql, triggers, user-defined-types

1.I create my datatype "FechaHistorica"

```
 --1-
create or replace TYPE exper.FechaHistorica as object(
anio integer,
mes integer,
dia integer
);
```

2- I create a table with 2 columns with my user datatype

```
CREATE TABLE exper.Persona(
persona varchar(20) not null,
nombre varchar(200) not null,
sexo varchar(1) not null,
fNacimiento ref FechaHistorica,
fMuerte ref FechaHistorica,
generales nclob,
constraint pkPersona primary key( persona ),
constraint chkSexo check( sexo = 'M' or sexo = 'm' or sexo = 'F' or sexo =   'f' )
);
```

3- In this function, what I'm trying to do is to pass either Fnacimiento or FMuerte. In this function I'm returning the value as 0 if the comprobations mark the value as correct.

```
--2-
create or replace function Validar(objeto in FechaHistorica)
return integer is
some_variable integer;
vBandera boolean;
begin
if(objeto.anio = null and objeto.mes=null and objeto.dia=null ) then
some_variable:=0;
elsif(objeto.anio = null and objeto.mes<>null and objeto.dia<>null) then
some_variable:=1;
elsif(objeto.mes = null and objeto.dia<>null) then
some_variable:=1;
elsif(objeto.anio<>null and objeto.mes<>null and objeto.dia = null) then
some_variable:=0;
end if;

--Comprabar mes y día.
if(some_variable = 0) then
if((objeto.mes>12) or (objeto.mes <1)) then
some_variable:=1;
elsif((objeto.mes = 02) or (objeto.mes = 2)) then
If objeto.anio Mod 4 = 0 Then
  If (objeto.anio Mod 100 = 0) And Not (objeto.anio Mod 400 = 0) Then
    vBandera := False;
    if(objeto.dia>28) then
      some_variable:=1;
    END IF;
  Else
    vBandera := True;
    if(objeto.dia>29) then
      some_variable:=1;
        END IF;
      End If;
    Else
    vBandera := False;
    End If;
  End if;
End if;
return some_variable;
end;
```

4- In this trigger I want to call the function, but I get an error wrong number or types of arguments on the call of the function. What should I do to correct this?

```
--3-
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER exper.some_trigger 
  before insert or update on exper.Persona for each row
  BEGIN
  if Validar(:New.fNacimiento) = 0 
    then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Fecha de Nacimiento Aceptada');
Else
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'Fecha de Nacimiento no aceptada');
  END IF;
  if Validar(:New.fMuerte) = 0 
    then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Fecha de Muerte Aceptada');
  Else
    raise_application_error(-20002, 'Fecha de Muerte no aceptada');
  END IF;
  END some_trigger;
```

Comment: maybe you should check in the trigger, that you pass a NOT NULL value to the procedure. btw for checking NULL values use `x IS NULL` instead of `x = NULL` and `x IS NOT NULL` instead of `x <> NULL`

Comment: can you provide a sample insert or update?

Answer (score 0):

remove "REF" in your table definition.

```
CREATE TABLE Persona(
persona varchar(20) not null,
nombre varchar(200) not null,
sexo varchar(1) not null,
fNacimiento FechaHistorica,
fMuerte  FechaHistorica,
generales nclob,
constraint pkPersona primary key( persona ),
constraint chkSexo check( sexo = 'M' or sexo = 'm' or sexo = 'F' or sexo =   'f' )
);
```

just wondering: why do you use an Object instead of a Date column?